# Music and Ringtones no longer found - Nexus 5 with Lollipop

Tags: nexus-5, google-play-music, 5.1-lollipop, ringtone

I have a stock Nexus 5 with 5.1.1

Since last Friday, Google Play Music can no longer access music put in the Music folder AND my custom ringtones which are in Ringtones folder can no longer be found.

- I've rebooted countless times.
- I've tried to Clear Cache and memory for Google Play Music
- I've tried to Clear cache for Storage
- I tried to use Android File Transfer to download the songs again but it won't even start
- I've used a File Manager app to confirm the files are in there
- I've used Poweramp and it is able to play the music
- If using File Manager, I tap on a song, Google Play Music can actually play it.

My next step would be to reset my phone but I really don't want to go there.

Comment: First step here would be to examine the logs (see our [logging tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info)). But apart from your musinc files, have other media files gone missing as well? Can e.g. your gallery app still find your photos? I'm suspecting the [media-scanner](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info) having issues.

Comment: ok will look at logs. Might be a bit. hmm good point. Pictures that were taken since Friday are there but anything before that is gone.

Comment: Might be a corrupted media database. If logs show the scanner is having issues, maybe resetting the database and then rebooting (or triggering the media-scanner in another way) should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up trying the following
1) Looking at the logs. Saw no smoking gun
2) Clearing the memory on the media storage. That didn't do it. Wasn't a good idea either. It couldn't see the pictures I had taken after the issue started.
3) Resetting the phone and restoring from backup. That did it. Bit painful.

Comment: I have what looks like the same problem on a 5X. Would appreciate if anyone can share a less drastic solution...